# Index '1' is out of valid index range '0' to '0' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'tp.Privileges'

Tags: c, winapi

Im using this function to adjust multiple privileges for the application at the same time but I run into this warning and I dont know how to fix it. I tried to do it with the union and offsetof but it didn't work. How would I allocate more memory for that structure?

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 0 };
    LUID luid1, luid2;

    OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken);

    LookupPrivilegeValueW(NULL, SE_DEBUG_NAME, &luid1);
    LookupPrivilegeValueW(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &luid2);

    //the code I tried
    union {
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
        unsigned char storage[offsetof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, Privileges) + sizeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES) * 2];
    };

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 2;
    
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    tp.Privileges[1].Luid = luid2; //the warning is here
    tp.Privileges[1].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED; //and here

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I don't know your intent with the union, but it has no instances and no name, so no instances can be created.

Comment: [Important  The constant ANYSIZE_ARRAY is defined as 1 in the public header Winnt.h. To create this array with more than one element, you must allocate sufficient memory for the structure to take into account additional elements.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_privileges) Since you haven't done that, trying to use  tp.Privileges[1] is wrong. You will have to use malloc to create a dynamically allocated TOKEN_PRIVILEGES object of the correct size.

Comment: Something like `TOKEN_PRIVILEGES* tp_ptr = malloc( sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES) + sizeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES) * (desired_array_size - 1) );`. And you must manually free this when your program is done with it.

Comment: @AviBerger That's not bow you'd calculate the correct size to allocate (see [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043)).

Comment: you can use such union `union { 
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
  struct { 
   ULONG PrivilegeCount; 
   LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[2];
  };
 };`

Comment: @IInspectable, Thanks for the link. I should more properly have used `(desired_array_size - ANYSIZE_ARRAY)` as Agent_L did rather than used the defined value. Otherwise, it is equivalent to article's method as far as I can see & is a way to do it without the Windows macro. Could also use offsetof without the subtraction. Article's issue was for a hypothetical alternate definition of TOKEN_PRIVILEGES.

Comment: @AviBerger [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) is a core language feature of C. And from your response, you've probably completely missed what the article is about. It provides a solution that's immune to alignment and padding, irrespective of the structures involved or the target architectures. All of that is *explicitly* spelled out in the article. [Agent_L's proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539551/1889329) is just as wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable, The article is about a _hypothetical_ `typedef struct _TOKEN_GROUPS {
    DWORD GroupCount;
} TOKEN_GROUPS, *PTOKEN_GROUPS;` versus the _real_ `typedef struct _TOKEN_GROUPS {
    DWORD GroupCount;
    SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Groups[ANYSIZE_ARRAY];
} TOKEN_GROUPS, *PTOKEN_GROUPS;`. The article's FIELD_OFFSET solution can't be used with the hypothetical structure since it does not have a Groups member and dealing with those serious alignment and padding issues would be really messy both in getting the allocation size and in use and not a good idea.

Comment: (cont) The actual struct def does have a Groups member, so can be used with the suggested Windows macro of `FIELD_OFFSET(TOKEN_GROUPS, Groups[NumberOfGroups])`. Rendered using C core language features this is offsetof( TOKEN_GROUPS, Groups) + sizeof(SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[NumberOfGroups]). AFAICT this is equivalent to what I and Agent_L have. You might want to review said article paying close attention to the real & hypothetical definiton of the struct.

Comment: Though re Agent_L's answer, I see no point in going through an intermediate void * pointer.

Comment: @AviBerger You may have to give the article another read. It seems you're still completely lost as to what the issue is. Your proposed `offsetof( TOKEN_GROUPS, Groups) + sizeof(SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[NumberOfGroups])` is **not** equivalent to `offsetof( TOKEN_GROUPS, Groups[NumberOfGroups] )`. The latter is correct, the former *sometimes* doesn't fail.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, `offsetof( TOKEN_GROUPS, Groups[NumberOfGroups] )` works, but is equivalent. Both work. **Neither** is what the article is about. The article is about a suggestion to pull this off without a Groups member in the struct. Having that (flexible array-like) member is what deals with the alignment and padding issues. Note this case has an array size of 1. If this was a true standard flexible array member (no size) [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct) is ambiguous, I don't know what the standard says for that case (which isn't ours).

Comment: And to throw more fuel on the fire, here is [Carnegie Mellon's Software Engineering Institute using the same calculation I did in both a noncompliant and a compliant code example](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member). This post is about the noncompliant case which Carnegie Mellon says has undefined behavior. That noncompliance is, however, due to how the Window's api defines the struct.

Answer (score 1):

The point of structures with trailing array of zero (or 1) size is to `malloc` a larger memory block and cast it to the struct.

```
DWORD numPriviledges = 5;
void* buffer = malloc (sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES) + sizeof(LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES) * (numPriviledges - ANYSIZE_ARRAY));
PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES ptp = (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) buffer;
ptp->PrivilegeCount = numPriviledges;
...
ptp->Privileges[4] = something;
...
AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, ptp, 0, NULL, 0);
ptp = NULL;
free(buffer);
buffer = NULL;
```

It's not meant to be allocated on stack, that's what the warning is trying to tell you.
It's poor man's flexible array member from C99

Answer (score 0):

you can use for instanse such code

```
union {         
    ::TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;      
    struct {
        ULONG PrivilegeCount;
        LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privileges[2];  
    };
};

PrivilegeCount = 2;
Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
Privileges[0].Luid = { SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE };
Privileges[1].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
Privileges[1].Luid = { SE_SHUTDOWN_PRIVILEGE };
AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, 0, 0, 0);
```

also note that 4-th parameter of `AdjustTokenPrivileges` *BufferLength* (where you pass `sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES)` ) related to 5-th parameter but not to 3-th (which size also not equal to `sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES)` ). so you need pass 0 here.

also not need use `LookupPrivilegeValueW` but possible use hardcoded constants, like `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` - it declared in *wdm.h*

also you not need `TOKEN_QUERY` here - this need only if the *PreviousState* parameter is not NULL,

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247707/discussion-on-answer-by-rbmm-index-1-is-out-of-valid-index-range-0-to-0-fo).